# Script works in the shell but not via GUI dd-wrt router

Tags: shell, dd-wrt

I have the following script working very well when I ssh into my dd-wrt router and issue the command

```
/opt/bin/curl --url "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "username@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "username@gmail.com" --upload-file /mnt/mail.txt --user "username@gmail.com:password" --insecure
```

but when I issue the same commands via GUI; Administration/commands then the same script doesn't work.

any working solution will be a great help, thanks

Comment: In whay way doesn't work? Does it give you an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Log in into the machine and type the command:

```
which sh
```

Put this value as a first line, preceding it with th #! characters, like

```
#!/bin/sh
```

What is your shell version? Look carefully at the first lines after you connected via ssh to your router. It's similar to:

```
BusyBox v1.15.3 (2011-11-24 00:44:20 CET) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

You may want to log the output of the command for debug purposes:

```
#!/bin/sh
/opt/bin/curl --url "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "username@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "username@gmail.com" --upload-file /mnt/mail.txt --user "username@gmail.com:password" --insecure 2>&1 | logger -t $0
```

It will log the output using syslog facility. If it happens you have no syslog installed, you can log the output to a file:

```
#!/bin/sh
/opt/bin/curl --url "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "username@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "username@gmail.com" --upload-file /mnt/mail.txt --user "username@gmail.com:password" --insecure >> /tmp/mylogfile 2>&1
```

Also, make sure, the script has an executable attribute set:

```
chmod a+rx /path/to/your/script
```

Comment: thanks Artur, I'll get get back to you with your suggestions.